# Definition of "bridge," "verse", "chorus" and "outro"

Tags: creative-writing, lyrics

It is common for lyrics to be divided into "bridge," "verse," "chorus" and "outro". Are these all written in the same way? If not, how do they tend to be different?

Generally, I see that the chorus has more-but-shorter lines than the other parts, but I am wondering if it's common to have them all look the same. Is there a guide that tells the difference of each part and how they should be different from one another?

Comment: Your question is unclear. (1) "the chorus is a bit longer and shorter than the other parts" Well, is it shorter or longer? It cannot be both. Or if it can be both, then that is your answer. (2) "sound the same", "look the same" What does "sound" and "look" mean here? With "sound", do you mean the music? We are a writing, not a music community. With "look", do you mean the layout or some visual aspect of writing lyrics? How is that relevant to lyrics? (3) Why do you post your text? Do you want feedback? That is off topic here.

Comment: I would suggest editing the post to remove the lyrics, since they aren't really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no universal standards, because different styles of music approach these differently (many don't even use verse-chorus-bridge) and even within a style, there's always individual variation.

With that caveat, however, here are some often-applicable guidelines:

- The "**chorus**" is called that because it's traditionally the part that everyone sings along with. So it's usually shorter, simpler, more repetitive, easier to remember and sing, and often has a "happier mood" then the verse. For the majority of songs, most people remember only the chorus. If your chorus isn't memorable, your song is unlikely to be successful. Usually the chorus is repeated (without significant modifications) several times in a song. The chorus often summarizes the "theme" of a song.
- The **verse** is often sung only by the lead singer. It accordingly can be considerably longer and more complex than the chorus (but does not have to be). Good songs often have verses that are challenging in some way. Each verse usually has new words, but with the same general melody and rhythm as the the other verses.
- The function of the **bridge** is to contrast with both the verse and the chorus (it adds novelty and interest to the song) so it can potentially be any length. Most often, the bridge only occurs once in the song.
- Many songs don't have an **outro**. If they do, the purpose is to give a closing feel to the song. Outros are often simple, and repetitive, often instrumental,

For some songs, the verse, chorus and bridge are all relatively similar, in other songs they contrast widely. If there are differences, here are some common ones:

- Verse uses minor chords, chorus uses major chords
- Bridge is a different key.
- Bridge is instrumental.
- Bridge uses chords or notes not found in the rest of the song.
- Verse is long, chorus is short.
- Verse is a rap, chorus is sung.
- Verse tells a story, chorus is a chant.
- Bridge changes the meaning of the song.
- Verse is sad or disturbing, chorus is happy and affirmative.
- Verse is a narrative, chorus is dialog.
- Bridge reveals a secret.
- Verse is rhythmically complex, chorus is simple.
- Verse rhymes, chorus doesn't (or vice versa)
- Chorus is an old cliche, verse is original.

Comment: Does my question need more clarity? I thought you did a good job at answering my question. I am not sure what's going on here.

Comment: @Sayaman I didn't think the question lacked clarity. I think the reason it was closed was because it seemed to focus on original writing. However, I did NOT vote to close it.